# javaFX: styleClass is not working in jar file

Tags: css, javafx-2, fxml

It's working fine while I am running the application directly from eclipse. but after building the application using ant, generated jar file it's not working.

However if I removed **Styleclass="theme"** from fxml it's working fine using jar file as well

**Java File**

```
public class MainClass extends Application {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}


@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
Parent root =   FXMLLoader.load(getClass().
getResource("/resources/fxmlDocument/Sample.fxml"));


stage.setTitle("SAMPLE");
Scene scene= new Scene(root);

scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getClassLoader().
getResource("resources/css/sample.css").toExternalForm());


stage.setScene(scene);
stage.setResizable(false);

stage.show();
}
}
```

**Fxml File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" styleClass="theme" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="com.integra.test.MainClassController">
  <children>
    <Label layoutX="300.0" layoutY="184.0" text="Great..!" />
    <Button fx:id="clickbutton" layoutX="207.0" layoutY="184.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="clickme" />
    <TextField fx:id="text1" layoutX="207.0" layoutY="220.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
    <Button fx:id="closebutton" layoutX="459.0" layoutY="318.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#closeButtonAction" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="Close" />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Please, show how do you add css to the scene in your app. And make sure you "Clean and Build" your project to ensure non-java files were properly updated in jar.

Comment: I have added code as well can you please look into it.

Comment: You are using getClass().getResource() and getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(), is there any reason why it is not consistent?

Comment: no I am just trying it in a different way..is it causing any issue.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also use this for adding Style sheets to the controls.

```
control.getStylesheets().add
 (MainClass.class.getResource("Sample.css").toExternalForm());
```

make sure css file in the same package or specify source path.

Second way is to use scene builder and add css using scene builder. You will get tutorial for this.